# Can you help me translate an inscription on an amulet for a friend?

Tags: translation

Can anyone help translate the inscription in the image below?

This is from a necklace/amulet that a friend picked up in Jerusalem many years ago. She asked me to translate it since I took some Hebrew in college, but that was 20+ years ago. I suspect this Hebrew text, written by someone years ago in Jerusalem, is from the Torah.

I can't make out any more than the name Jerusalem.

[image: Metal amulet with engraved Hebrew letters]

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501). Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

אם אשכחך ירושלים תשכח ימיני *Im eshkachek Yerushalayim tishkach yemini*

"If I forget you O Jerusalem, may my right hand forget its skill." The words are from [Psalms 137:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26d7.htm).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79121/discussion-on-answer-by-ezra-can-you-help-me-translate-an-inscription-on-an-amul).